# PHP: Changing the privacy status of a video through YouTube API

Tags: php, youtube-api

I'm wondering how to update the privacy status of a video in youtube api. the update snippet goes like this.

```
     $updateVideo = new Google_Video($video);
     $updateSnippet = new Google_VideoSnippet($videoSnippet);

     $updateSnippet->setTitle($title);
     $updateSnippet->setDescription($description);
     $updateSnippet->setTags($tags);

     $updateVideo -> setSnippet($updateSnippet);

     $updateResponse = $youtube->videos->update("snippet", $updateVideo);
     $responseTags = $updateResponse['snippet'];
```

that is considering if you are updating the title, description and tags. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this...

```
// Create a video status with privacy status. Options are "public", "private" and "unlisted".


 $updateVideo = new Google_Video($video);
 $updateSnippet = new Google_VideoSnippet($videoSnippet);

 $updateSnippet->setTitle($title);
 $updateSnippet->setDescription($description);
 $updateSnippet->setTags($tags);

$status = new Google_VideoStatus();//here
$status->privacyStatus = "private";//here
 $updateVideo -> setSnippet($updateSnippet);
$updateVideo->setStatus($status);//and here

//Updated this line to have "status,snippet"
 $updateResponse = $youtube->videos->update("status,snippet", $updateVideo);
 $responseTags = $updateResponse['snippet'];
```

Comment: i'm getting a fatal error 'google_serviceException' saying error calling PUT.

Comment: Try changing:
$updateResponse = $youtube->videos->update("snippet", $updateVideo);
To:
$updateResponse = $youtube->videos->update("status,snippet", $updateVideo);